# Using SAX parser, need all the xml elements(under a particular element) as a string

Tags: java, xml, saxparser

I need all the xml elements(under a particular element) as a string from the below xml using sax parser.

sample xml:

```
<root>
  <meta>
    <elememtA>xx</elememtA>
  </meta>
 <payload>
    <parent>
        <child1>a</child1>
   </parent>
   <parent>
        <child1>b</child1>
   </parent>
  </payload>
</root>
```

Sax parser implementation:

```
public class UserHandler extends DefaultHandler {  
    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, 
    String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)
    throws SAXException {
    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("payload")) {
    //need all elements inside payload as string
}
```

for example,

I need the fallowing output:

```
<parent><child1>a</child1></parent><parent><child2>b</child2></parent>
```

Comment: hi,think that you mean : <parent><child1>a</child1></parent><parent><child2>b</child2></parent>

Comment: hi, i didnt get you

Comment: just edited the post, the second argument was <child2>b<child2>

Comment: String or an array of bytes?

Comment: For String input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is working code.
you can see your result at bottom line of output. Enjoy.

**Output**

```
2017-06-14 09:43:49 DEBUG SaxTest:94 - start document
2017-06-14 09:43:49 DEBUG SaxTest:107 - START -  - parent
2017-06-14 09:43:49 DEBUG SaxTest:107 - START -  - child1
2017-06-14 09:43:49 DEBUG SaxTest:33 - STRING : a
2017-06-14 09:43:49 DEBUG SaxTest:52 - END -  - child1
2017-06-14 09:43:49 DEBUG SaxTest:52 - END -  - parent
2017-06-14 09:43:49 DEBUG SaxTest:107 - START -  - parent
2017-06-14 09:43:49 DEBUG SaxTest:107 - START -  - child1
2017-06-14 09:43:49 DEBUG SaxTest:33 - STRING : b
2017-06-14 09:43:49 DEBUG SaxTest:52 - END -  - child1
2017-06-14 09:43:49 DEBUG SaxTest:52 - END -  - parent
2017-06-14 09:43:49 DEBUG SaxTest:41 - end document
2017-06-14 09:43:49 INFO  SaxTest:148 - RESULT 
<parent><child1>a</child1></parent><parent><child1>b</child1></parent>
```

**Code in Junit - with the working test**

```
package com.rizze.beans.labs.sof;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.Locator;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

public class SaxTest {

    public static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SaxTest.class);


    public class SaxProcess implements ContentHandler {

        private boolean start= false;
        private static final String START_ITEM = "payload";
        private String result = "";

        @Override
        public void characters(char[] ch, int begin, int length) throws SAXException {
            if(start == true){
                logger.debug("STRING : "+new String(ch).substring(begin,begin+length));

                result+=new String(new String(ch).substring(begin,begin+length));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
                        logger.debug("end document");
        }

        @Override
        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String name) throws SAXException {

            if(name!=null && name.compareToIgnoreCase(START_ITEM)==0){
                start = false;
            }
            else{
                if(start == true){
                    logger.debug("END - "+ localName + " - " + name);
                    result+="</"+name+">";
                }
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void endPrefixMapping(String prefix) throws SAXException {



        }

        @Override
        public void ignorableWhitespace(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {

        }

        @Override
        public void processingInstruction(String target, String data) throws SAXException {


        }

        @Override
        public void setDocumentLocator(Locator locator) {

        }

        @Override
        public void skippedEntity(String name) throws SAXException {


        }

        @Override
        public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
            start=false;
            result = "";

            logger.debug("start document");
        }

        @Override
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {

            if(name!=null && name.compareToIgnoreCase(START_ITEM)==0){
                start = true;
            }
            else{

                if(start == true){
                    //if already started ... go on
                    logger.debug("START - "+ localName + " - " + name);
                    result+="<"+name+">";
                }
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void startPrefixMapping(String prefix, String uri) throws SAXException {


        }

        /**
         * return resulting string
         * @return
         */
        public String getResult(){
            return result;
        }

    }





    @Test
    public void test() {


        String xml = "<root><meta><elememtA>xx</elememtA></meta><payload><parent><child1>a</child1></parent><parent><child1>b</child1></parent></payload></root>";
        InputSource in = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));


            try {
                XMLReader  reader= SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser().getXMLReader();
                SaxProcess p=new SaxProcess();
                reader.setContentHandler(p);
                reader.parse(in);
                logger.info("RESULT \n"+p.getResult());
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }

}
```

Comment: @svasa => the question was how to I use  ContentHandler in SAX. this code respond to the question, and also works in a single file. If you take out the logging / imports...., you will reduice the code size by 50%.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need an output in xml form ,i.e. you need the `parent` nodes in xml form. The SAXParser or XPath engine works with nodes and names of nodes. You have to write special code to return the desired output as xml which can be very cumbersome and hard to maintain.

One way to easily get the desired output xml is to use XSLT.

Consider using XSLT :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="//payload/parent"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

place this in a file called `parentxslt.xml`, and put your input xml in `parent.xml`, then you could use below java code :

```
try
{
    File stylesheet = new File( "parentxslt.xml" );
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer( new StreamSource(stylesheet) );
    StreamSource xmlSource = new StreamSource( new File( "parent.xml" ) );
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    transformer.transform( xmlSource, new StreamResult( sw ) );

    System.out.println( sw.toString().replaceAll("\\\r\\n\\s*", "") );

}
catch ( Exception ex )
{
   ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Don't create a DOM just because you want to transform it. It's much better to supply the transformer with a StreamSource or SAXSource.

Comment: @MichaelKay Thanks for the comment! I updated my code to use `StreamSource`

Comment: Also, why not reduce it to `<xsl:copy-of select="//payload/parent"/>`?

Comment: @MichaelKay Thanks again. modified xsl too.